# How to check if a page in viewpager is visible in java

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-viewpager, android-camera

I have been searching the internet for an hour and I created custom views for viewPager. Every solution I saw was for Fragments. My question is how to check, using an if statement if my page is visible. I want to do this for one reason. I have certain views that lay on top of the camera screen and want to save each picture depending on what the view is. For example: if the "TOPS" clothes object and "tops_view" is being used, I want to save it to a "tops" folder in android. I already know how to save to different folders so I want to make if statements in my cameraAPI file. The if statement is the pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

```js
if (ClothesPagerView == TOPS)

final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/OutfitMatcher/tops/img" + System.currentTimeMillis () +".jpg");

else if (ClothesPagerView == BOTTOMS)

final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/OutfitMatcher/bottoms/img" + System.currentTimeMillis () +".jpg");
```

CustomPagerAdapater.java

```js
public class CustomPagerAdapter1 extends PagerAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomPagerAdapter1(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        ClothesObject clothesObject = ClothesObject.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(clothesObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ClothesObject.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        ClothesObject customPagerEnum = ClothesObject.values()[position];
        return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
    }
}
```

ClothesObject.jaca (that I use with the adapter)

```js
public enum ClothesObject {
    TOPS(R.string.tops_camera, R.layout.tops_view),
    BOTTOMS(R.string.bottoms_camera, R.layout.bottoms_view),
    ACCESSORIES(R.string.accessories_camera, R.layout.accessories_view),
    SHOES(R.string.shoes_camera, R.layout.shoes_view),
    OUTERWEAR(R.string.outerwear_camera, R.layout.outerwear_view),
    DRESSES(R.string.dresses_camera, R.layout.dresses_view);

    private int mTitleResId;
    private int mLayoutResId;

    ClothesObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
        mTitleResId = titleResId;
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return mTitleResId;
    }

    public int getLayoutResId() {
        return mLayoutResId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to use fragment with Viewpager. then you can use `getUserVisibleHint()` in your fragment for checking if page is active or not

ie,

```
    if(getUserVisibleHint()){
    //Your fragment is visible
    }else{
      // Not visible
}
```

Comment: the getUserVisibleHint is red with "cannot resolve method"

Comment: First you have to chage your pager adapter to FragmentPagerAdapter, then use fragments for creating view. then use  getUserVisibleHint() for checking fragment is visible or not

Comment: Would this erase my "views" or would i have to recreate them?

Comment: No. you can use this same logic in fragment too